# XML tree deleting nodes

Tags: python, xml

EDIT: 
This code works:

```
def randomize_model(self, model_path):
    tree = ET.parse(model_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for body in root.iter('body'):
        regex = re.compile(F'object[0-{self.num_blocks}]')
        if re.match(regex, body.attrib['name']):
            body.set('mass', str(np.random.choice(np.logspace(-6.64, 1, base=2)))) # in KG, logarithmically sampled from .01 kg to 1kg
            body.set('friction', str(np.random.choice(np.logspace(-3.3, 2.32, base=2)))) # .1, 5
            body.set('damping', str(np.random.choice(np.logspace(-6.64, -2.3, base=2)))) #
            # TODO: scale size so that larger blocks are heavier
            # ET.SubElement(root[3], body)
    new_tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    new_tree.write(F"/tmp/stack{self.num_blocks}.xml")
    return
```

**But the below doesn't. Why?** 
- I think part of it is a silent error because the np.random.choice ... is not a string. But why is there no exception or error raised by ElementTree? I had no visibility as to what was causing the issue

```
def randomize_model(self, model_path):
    tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(model_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    bodies = root.iter('body')
    for body in bodies:
# The logic below ends up deleting the 'body' nodes for some reason

        regex = re.compile(F'object[0-{self.num_blocks}]')
        if re.match(regex, body.attrib['name']):
            body.set('mass', np.random.choice(np.logspace(-6.64, 1, base=2))) # in KG, logarithmically sampled from .01 kg to 1kg
            body.set('friction', np.random.choice(np.logspace(-3.3, 2.32, base=2))) # .1, 5
            body.set('damping', np.random.choice(np.logspace(-6.64, -2.3, base=2))) #
    tree.write(F"/tmp/output2.xml")
    return
```

Why does this code delete the "body" nodes found in the for loop? The tree.write line sees the nodes completely erased.

To tell that the nodes are deleted, check /tmp/output2.xml All XML elements with name = object* are removed. Gone from the file.

---

This is the model_xml.xml that is loaded into the above model_path of randomize_model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mujoco>
    <compiler angle="radian" coordinate="local" meshdir="../stls/fetch" texturedir="../textures"></compiler>
    <option timestep="0.002">
        <flag warmstart="enable"></flag>
    </option>

    <include file="shared.xml"></include>

    <worldbody>
        <geom name="floor0" pos="0.8 0.75 0" size="0.85 0.70 1" type="plane" condim="3" material="floor_mat"></geom>
        <body name="floor0" pos="0.8 0.75 0">
            <site name="target0" pos="0 0 0.5" size="0.02 0.02 0.02" rgba="0 1 0 0.3" type="sphere"></site>
            <site name="target1" pos="0 0 0.5" size="0.02 0.02 0.02" rgba="1 1 0 0.3" type="sphere"></site>
        </body>

        <include file="robot.xml"></include>

        <body pos="1.3 0.75 0.2" name="table0">
            <geom size="0.25 0.35 0.2" type="box" mass="2000" material="table_mat"></geom>
        </body>

        <body name="object0" pos="0.025 0.025 0.025">
            <joint name="object0:joint" type="free" damping="0.01"></joint>
            <geom size="0.025 0.025 0.025" type="box" condim="3" name="object0" material="block0_mat" mass="2"></geom>
            <site name="object0" pos="0 0 0" size="0.02 0.02 0.02" rgba="1 0 0 1" type="sphere"></site>
        </body>

        <body name="object1" pos="0.025 0.025 0.025">
            <joint name="object1:joint" type="free" damping="0.01"></joint>
            <geom size="0.025 0.025 0.025" type="box" condim="3" name="object1" material="block1_mat" mass="2"></geom>
            <site name="object1" pos="0 0 0" size="0.02 0.02 0.02" rgba="1 0 0 1" type="sphere"></site>
        </body>

        <light directional="true" ambient="0.2 0.2 0.2" diffuse="0.8 0.8 0.8" specular="0.3 0.3 0.3" castshadow="false" pos="0 0 4" dir="0 0 -1" name="light0"></light>
    </worldbody>

    <actuator>
        <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="0 0.2" joint="robot0:l_gripper_finger_joint" kp="30000" name="robot0:l_gripper_finger_joint" user="1"></position>
        <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="0 0.2" joint="robot0:r_gripper_finger_joint" kp="30000" name="robot0:r_gripper_finger_joint" user="1"></position>
    </actuator>
</mujoco>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your behavior, works as expected. *"np.random.choice ... is not a string"*: Yes, should be `str`. *`re.compile(`* are intended to be used **outside** a `loop` and looks invalid `re` expression.

Comment: So when you ran the second randomize_model function, you get an exception?

Comment: What is the effect of having re.compile inside the function? That part seems to work no problem

Comment: *"get an exception?"*: Yes, **`TypeError: cannot serialize x (type int)`** *"having re.compile inside the function?"*: Inside `function` doesn't matter, inside a `loop` slows down.